# Is there an Open Office xml editor alternative to Visual Studio Lightswitch?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, openxml

Can anyone suggest me an open source alternative to Visual Studio LightSwitch? I need it for editing open office xml documents (docx, pptx, xlsx etc.) since renaming the document, unzipping it, editing it and then rezipping it is too cumbersome. Compatibility with either windows or linux is fine (though i would prefer windows).

Thnx in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a Chrome Extension, where We can view the OpenXML document without renaming and unZip. But we cant edit document.

You can get it here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ooxml-tools/bjmmjfdegplhkefakjkccocjanekbapn

Or If you use winrar or winzip, associate the OpenXML formats under integration section.

Hope this helps.

Comment: really helpful thanx but I am looking for a way to edit these xml files and then repackage them so as to create a new edited openxml document (docx, pptx etc.)

Comment: I don't know anything about LightSwitch. but, in Visual Studio there is an Extension called "Open XML Package Editor Power Tool for Visual Studio 2010" which i'm using. You can get it here. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/450a00e3-5a7d-4776-be2c-8aa8cec2a75b.
Sorry if you are referring the same!

Comment: its not the same but its similar. Unfortunately though, it is not open source and buying a licensed product for some very minor work like mine seems like an overkill...

Comment: This Open XML package editor is free to use but you should have visual studio to use it. You can edit documents in visual studio itself.

Comment: Yes but visual studio itself is not open source. But i guess if nothing else is working I would just purchase it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a VS Code extension for viewing and editing Office Open XML files (I'm one of the contributors)

It is available on the [VS Code Marketplace page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mikeebowen.ooxml-validator-vscode)

and you can view the code on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/yuenm18/ooxml-viewer-vscode)